# placeholder for storing temp values in c# thread context

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to store some info (key value pair) in a c# thread context or similar ( just like httpcontext for a web request ).

I want to be able to store this info (key value pair) somewhere in thread context ( or something similar) so that my code can always read these values from the current thread its running under.

In my appliation i have a chain of API calls and its not possible to pass this info from one method to other ( already dsicarded this option! )

**note** - this thread is running as an async operation inside an Asp.Net application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [Thread Local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh.aspx) using the [ThreadStatic attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) ?

```
public static class ThreadLocalExample
{
    // There will be one Foo instance per thread.
    // Each thread will have to initialize it's own instance.
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Foo bar;
}
```

Of course you could add some helper methods or properties to the above to help you manage the instance, including ensuring initialization on each thread.

Comment: Fixed the attribute ThreadLocal -> ThreadStatic hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Chris, of course, it should be ThreadStatic. Thanks for correcting.